# mssql index search fails when fields integer are cast to varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, indexing

scenario: mssql server 2008 (IMPORTANT:  I cant modify the database)

```
table name: model,  index id INTEGER(18) AND model INTEGER(18)
field id integer(18)    (i.e. 123)
field model integer(18)  (i.e. 456)
....

table name: product, index model VARCHAR(200)
field model varchar(200) (contains model.id & model.model) (i.e. 123456)
....
```

the sentence:

```
select top 100 p.*,m.* from p
left join MODEL m  on p.MODEL= CAST(m.cvid as varchar(18))+ CAST(m.MODEL as varchar(18))
```

performs a table scan. why? 
I also tried CAST(m.cvid as varchar)+ CAST(m.MODEL as varchar) without success

Add:
I have thousands of p and thousands of m. The index is relevant.

Comment: Why not?, you are not using any filter at all, and also using `*`, meaning that you want every row and every column from that table. In that scenario, using an index is the worst choice

Comment: You're right. My scenario was not complete- Guess is complete now. (Really, I have 3 tables: model, brand and material making a join to product).

Comment: I don't see how that changes the scenario

Comment: select top 100:  If I have a million records on "p" and a million records on "m" and I ask for first 100 "p" join "m" records, the engine dont have to make a table scan on the "m" million records 100 times... The engine must search for an index to do that task. Thats the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It performs a table scan on `product` because you don't have an `ORDER BY` to specify an order or a `WHERE` clause to filter the data.

It performs a table scan on `model` because there is no index on the join condition `CAST(m.cvid as varchar(18))+ CAST(m.MODEL as varchar(18))`

Comment: But the engine must(?) search for an index to do that task. "m" has an index containing id+model = "123456" (as I show in the sample) and "p" has a field model containing "123456". One field is numeric, the other is varchar, but BOTH has the same value "123456".

Comment: Converting the compound index to a concatenated character string must not be sargable - you could either add an index that does the string concatenation or change the comparison to break apart the string into two numbers.

Comment: In "index id INTEGER(18) , model INTEGER(18)" comma mean a plus. Sorry about that. I corrected it. But the idea, isn't clear? How can I can make sql recognize the index and use it, without enforcing it? cast varchar?, convert? create an index with an special issue?

Comment: So your index is on `id` + `model`, not a compound index?  That's going to give you a numeric result (e.g. id=18, model = 30 would give an "index" value of 48.  Like I said, you either need to add an index with the concatenation or break up the string into the two numbers.